# Twilio functions "live logs" sometimes don't log when toggle is "on"

Tags: twilio

When I toggle "on" Live Logs in the Twilio Functions editor, I sometimes get logging output and often times I don't.

I don't close the page that I have Live Logging turned on.

I can always get logging output by triggering the function directly from incoming call after reloading the page. After reloading the page, Live Logs is toggled to "off". I turn it on and call the number that is set to trigger the function. This is the only reliable way I can get logging.

I've tried toggling Live Logs on and off, even several times, to no avail.

Sometimes when I leave the Functions Editor page open and navigate to another Chrome page, when I come back to the Functions Editor page that I had left open, the Live Logs toggle has somehow turned off.

When I hit deploy with the Live Log turned on, after the build, the toggle is still on, but no logging - until I reload the page and then turn the toggle back on.

I have spent quite a bit of time fidgiting with this toggle and it's behaviour and I just can't figure it out.

I can't get logging output at all if the function is triggered from a Studio Flow.

Since I am new to Twilio programming, this logging behavior is making the Twilio learning curve very cumbersome.

I am looking for some guidance on how to correctly use the Live Logs as Twilio has intended.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably not the answer you want to hear, but it's the intended behavior that the toggle turns off again after some time and that it is off by default when reloading the page. I understand that the developer experience could be better here, but the web UI currently only works this way.

A possible workaround that I often use is printing the logs via the [Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/api/resource/logs#stream-live-logs-in-the-browser)

```
twilio serverless:logs --tail \
    --service-sid ZSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --environment ZEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

You can retrieve the environment SID with the following command if you don't know it:

```
twilio api:serverless:v1:services:environments:list --service-sid ZSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Any tips on how to get logging to work at all when the function is invoked via a flow? Also, it seems like a bug that the logging doesn't work when the toggle is in the ON position!!!

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just doubled checked with the team and they confirmed it's a bug that's on their radar :)

Comment: Yes I'm facing the same issue

Comment: is there a ticket number for that bug? any way to track that?

Comment: I'm afraid no, it's an internal system

Comment: The suggested work-around seems to not work with logs generated by serverless functions that are created in the ui.

Comment: I just tested it and it should work for them too. I added another command above that you can use the fetch the right environment sid (maybe that's missing)

Comment: @IObert I tried the above and still getting no logs from serverless:logs even with the service and environment sids set. I'm using console.log() in the code. I'm deploying my function via CLI only and not using the web ui. I can only see the POSTs for my functions in the web UI Logs -> Calls section. Nothing from the console.log() calls

Comment: @ski_squaw This means like a different issue than what is mentioned above. Can you please open a new question with a minimal code sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @iobert My logs started working again last Friday, perhaps Twilio rolled out an update. I didn't change anything on my side.